# Multi-module deploy with Maven, JBoss and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, jboss

Is there a way to do incremental deployments with these three tools when in a multi-module project?

Example of Maven project:

- project
- project-data
- project-service
- project-webapp

The above are Maven modules with dependencies between them. The project-webapp module contains the .war file, but I don't want to create a new .war file every time I need to deploy. Is there a way to perform deployments upon file saves?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Eclipse WTP support (and either the maven eclipse plugin or m2eclipse to import your project as a dynamic project). Did you try? Are you facing any particular problem?